# Suppress Save Dialogs in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Every time I close Notepad++ it asks to save files.

I remember a version that did not do this, it just closed and when reopened the unsaved documents were still there.

Is there a way to go back to this, without downgrading?

Comment: First off, are you talking about Notepad or Notepad++?

Comment: notepad++, i have amended the above.

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/951598/notepad-is-there-a-setting-to-stop-from-asking-me-to-save-on-exit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is notepad++ you set this to save to a default path by using Preferences>New Document/Default directory>Custom and mapping the location for default saves.  this intern will stop the message you are seeing

Comment: edit--> you can also restart from where you left off using the >Follow the current document option

Comment: This answer appears to be out of date at 2015/08/06

Comment: the original feature is now back in N++.