# Switch back Notepad++ to normal mode when in Administrator mode

Tags: windows-10, notepad++

When editing source code files in `program files` folder, Notepad++ has a handy feature that reopens it in **administrator mode** (if you have admin rights). Thus it allows saving those files.

But since Notepad++ is now in **Administrator mode**. It is very restrictive; it does not allow remote editing and other features that normal mode do.

Is there a way to **revert back to Normal mode** with a click of a button/menu? (I can restart Notepad++, but that seems tedious).

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a plugin for it. It can be easily done using the AutoHotKey(1). Without it, it can be done by pressing two keyboard shortcuts in sequence(2). Please let me know whether you are interested in option 1 or 2.

Comment: @miroxlav what is the second option - two keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Are you referring to the nppSaveAsAdmin plugin?

Comment: It is possible to set up the environment that one keyboard shortcut reliably exits N++ and second one starts it. Are you interested? (Easier than this, I can imagine only the AutoHotKey doing the same in single step.)

Comment: @miroxlav sure.

Comment: @NotepadPlusPlusPRO – maybe you now understand that transition to administrator mode actually restarts Notepad++. Therefore, there is no other way than restart to return back to normal mode. This is given by Windows architecture, where an application cannot change its admin mode flag after it was started. Giving you a shortcut to achieve restart is the only way to return back to the normal mode. (Sure, a plugin can be written for this, but it will do the same anyway.) You can consider accepting the answer showing how to perform an instant restart of N++.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using two keyboard shortcuts in sequence.

■ **Preparation (only once):**

1. [set Notepad++ to exit without prompt](https://superuser.com/q/951598/287473). So from now on, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> will immediately exit Notepad++ (keeping everything saved).
2. Pin Notepad++ into fixed position on the taskbar so its icon is there even if it is not running. For example, let's say you used 4th position so you can activate the icon by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

■ **Quick manual restart:**

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

■ **Quick restart where [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) sends the above keys** for you when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (or whatever else you choose):

```
; only if Notepad++ window is active
#IfWinActive Notepad++
^!r::
   Send !{F4}
   Sleep 1000
   Send #4
   Return
```

You can adjust `Sleep 1000` (milliseconds) to other value which works for you.

Comment: How does this change the problem with admin mode? This answer simply shows people how to close and start the application via windows shortcuts

Comment: @KalamalkaKid – transition to admin mode does a restart. Similarly, transition to normal mode is achieved using restart of N++.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining that. Is there way to tell which mode NP++ is currently running in ?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid – yes, in window title of N++, there is added indicator saying `[Administrator]`.